# bash scripts with option flags inconsistent behavior

Tags: bash, for

The code below is an mwe based on a script `mwe` I've written where I specify flags in what I think is the usual way.     But I'm seeing really wierd behavior.    If I type `mwe -e` or `mwe -n` it thinks there are no arguments and returns `no arg`.    If I type `mwe -k` or `mwe -i` it thinks `argType` is not `"-"` and returns `breaking`.    If I comment out the four lines that end with a `#` the code works as expected.     That suggests the problem is being caused by the `while` loop.       Could somebody please explain what's happening?

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=0
argType=`echo "$1" | cut -c 1`
while [ 1 -gt 0 ] ;   #
    do   #
        if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
            echo no arg
            exit
        elif [ "$argType" != "-" ] ; then
            #No more flags
            echo breaking
            break  #
        elif [ "$1" = "-n"  ] ; then
            foo=1
            shift
        elif [ "$1" = "-e"  ] ; then
            foo=2
            shift
        elif [ "$1" = "-i"  ] ; then
            foo=3
            shift
        elif [ "$1" = "-k"  ] ; then
            foo=4
            shift
        fi
done  #
echo This is foo:  $foo
```

Comment: `-n` and `-e` are likely being consumed as arguments to `echo`...

Comment: Are you aware that `getopts` will handle most of this for you?

Comment: See also: [How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts) in BashFAQ, [An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash) on SO, and, [the POSIX description of `getopts`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/getopts.html), which also has an example of usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is not clear what you want !

Anyhow it seems that you want the number corresponding to the last argument

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
foo=0;

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "${1}" in
        '-n')
            foo=1;
            shift
        ;;
        '-e')
            foo=2;
            shift
        ;;
        '-i')
            foo=3;
            shift
        ;;
        '-k')
            foo=4;
            shift
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Invalid flag";
            exit 1;
        ;;
    esac
done

echo "This is foo: $foo"
```

If instead you want a mechanism that treats and validates arguments before being processed, you can use something like

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

inputf='';
outputf='';
text='';
format='';

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]];do
    case "${1}" in
        '-i')
            inputf="${2}";
            shift 2
        ;;
        '-o')
            outputf="${2}";
            shift 2
        ;;
        '-t')
            text="${2}";
            shift 2
        ;;
        '-f')
            format="${2}";
            shift 2
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: first suggestion is great, thanks.   would you mind adding an extra case for me, which would deal with unintended flags, e.g., if I typed -G it would return "flag not recognized" and exit

Comment: for other cases we use glob star `*` that will catche anything other than valid flags

Answer (score 6):

Third line should be

```
argType=$(printf "%s" "$1" | cut -c 1)
```

As mentioned in comments, `echo` interprets arguments such as `-e` as an option, so that `-e` would not be passed to `cut`. Worse,  as a special case, [end-of-options flag `--` is not available to `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_04). Then, you need `printf`, [which is usually better anyway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803).

Since you are in `bash`, you could adopt @steeldriver's suggestion and use `argType=${1:0:1}` (which means: For parameter 1, start at char 0 and get 1 char) instead of the pipeline. Notice that is not available in the POSIX shell, however.

Also prefer `$()` instead of backticks, since the latter harm readability, especially when nesting.

Finally, notice that you are shifting, so, even after that correction, if you try `./myscript -e -i`, eventually `[ $# -eq 0 ]` will be true and the execution will be terminated by `exit`. Maybe that is intended, maybe not, but at the end of the day the last `echo` would not be triggered.

Comment: Also, the assignment to `argType` is before the loop, so it doesn't get updated as options are processed; it needs to be moved inside the loop to work right. Or, since this is bash, you could just use `elif [[ "$1" != "-"* ]]; ...` (note that this type of pattern matching requires a double-bracket conditional expression instead of just a single-bracket test).

Comment: If they're using [a POSIX shell, they could use `getopts`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/getopts.html)... Also, there's the hilarious `"${1%"${1#?}"}"` that works in stead of `${1:0:1}`